# Android apk taking gson.jar as a native platform

Tags: android, apk, google-play

I'm building my apk using android studio, the problem is that i'm getting "Devices supported : 0"

I suspect it's because i'm using gson, and it is taking it as a native platform.
[image]

Any idea how to fix this ?

Thank you.

Comment: Are you trying to add a 3rd party jar (gson.jar) to your project?  If so, I think you just add the jar to the libs folder in Eclipse.

Comment: I'm using Android studio, not eclipse. But my jar is in the libs folder. Anything additional i should do ?